# Laravel 4 - Artisan error SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a new migration for my users table, I have the following schema:

```
        Schema::create('users', function($t) {
            $t->increments('id');
            $t->string('username', 16);
            $t->string('password', 64);
            $t->integer('role', 64);
            $t->timestamps();
    });
```

When I try to run php artisan migrate from the terminal, I get the following error:

> [Exception]
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect
>   table definition; there can be      only one auto column and it must
>   be defined as a key (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigne     d
>   not null auto_increment primary key, `username` varchar(16) not null,
>   `password` varchar(64) no     t null, `role` int not null
>   auto_increment primary key, `created_at` timestamp default 0 not null 
>   , `updated_at` timestamp default 0 not null)) (Bindings: array (
>   ))

The error has something to do with the 'role' field, as when this is removed it seems to run fine.

Thanks in advance for any help or insight.

Comment: Why does the generated SQL set `role` to `auto_increment primary key`? What's wrong with `id` being the only `auto_increment primary key` column?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The second parameter for `integer` is an auto increment flag.

```php
public function integer($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false)
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L510

Comment: @TheRabbitFactory, I know it is a while ago, but do you know what I need to do, because I have the same problem as you

Comment: I don't really remember but I think I was basically missing that second parameter.

Comment: it's pretty clear in this answer? you can't set size of an integer field

Comment: [MySQL's docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html) make clearer that the size for the integer data types are pre-set. When you look at CREATE TABLE code though, you will more than likely see something like `INT(10)`, but this appears to be a conventional thing, since the max/min signed and unsigned value has 10 digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
$t->integer('role', false);
```

That fixes it.

Comment: Can you explain why that fixes it?

Comment: Answer without explanation are of no use.

Comment: by setting integer to false i disable autoIncrement this is why we bypass error.

Answer (score 0):

Length attribute of integer is not permitted.Remove it and try.