# How can I make auto-increment columns non-auto-increment?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am trying to create a table with this code.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('BookInfo', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('bookId',11);
        $table->string('Name',255);
        $table->string('Publisher')->nullable();
        $table->integer('Publishing_year',4)->nullable();
        $table->integer('Price',5)->nullable();
        $table->string('Language',30);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

When I tried `php artisan migrate` it shows me this error.

> `[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect
>   table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must
>   be defined as a key (SQL: create table`BookInfo`(`bookId`int not
>   null auto_increment primary key,`Name`varchar(255) not null,`
>   Publisher`varchar(255) null,`Publishing_year`int null 
>   auto_increment primary key,`Price`int null auto_increment primary key,`
>   Language`varchar(30) not null,`created_at`timestamp default 0
>   not null,`updated_at`timestamp default 0 not null) default character
>   set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)` and
>
> `[PDOException]
>
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect
>   table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be
>   defined as a key`

It seems laravel takes all the integer columns as auto-increment.What happened here actually and what will be solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$table->integer('bookId',11);` is not syntactically correct in Eloquent ORM(**you can't set any size limit for integers**) and that is causing the error in your case.

And `$table->increments('id');` automatically sets `id` as a `primary key`.

Find all necessary table building commands in Eloquent ORM here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#adding-columns

Answer (score 3):

The error says it all,

```
$table->integer('bookId',11);
                          ^// this is considered as autoincrement rather than length
```

There is no length option for integers

See [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/330d11ba8cd3d6c0a54a1125943526b126147b5f/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L443)

References on SO, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876491/laravel-4-migration-error-creates-two-auto-increment-primary-keys-fields) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931802/laravel-4-artisan-error-sqlstate42000)